# Parsing Windows CSV versus regular CSV

Tags: php, csv

I built an app that takes in a CSV as a bulk feed and I've notice a difference in CSVs when it is saved as a "Windows Comma Separated" vs. "Comma Separated" when saving in Excel on Mac. My script can only parse the Windows version and I can't see how to overcome this in my code.

I found out that they're different in the lines returns: http://cl.ly/image/3x463O3b0A1s

Here is the filetype list in Mac Excel: http://cl.ly/image/2F110Q1X0V0i

I explode it into lines like so:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
```

With the regular CSV, it doesn't recognize any lines, but with the Windows version it works as expected (go figure!). How do I fix this?

Comment: why use explode, there are built in csv handling functions. str_getcsv(), fgetcsv()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned before, you should use `fgetcsv()` ... However, I still had problems with CSVs generated on Macs using that function.

PHP was not properly detecting line endings. To overcome the issue, I had to add `ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);` to the function that was processing the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, use the native PHP functions: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv), [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv)

Comment: I use it after the explode in order to fix my other code around it better; within the $lines loop.